# Pdo prepared statement inserts NULL into table fields, oop php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create an oop login system and got stuck on this one

Soo, this is my insertion class

```
include_once 'db.php';

class loginHandler extends db {

    private $login;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct ($l,$p,$e) {

        $this->login = $l;
        $this->password = $p;
        $this->email = $e;
        $this->stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO users (log,pwd,email) VALUES (?,?,?);");

    }

    public function send () {

        $this->stmt->execute([$this->login,$this->password,$this->email]);

    }

}
```

And this is where the Submit button goes

```
include 'loginHandler.php';

$log = $_POST['log'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$em = $_POST['email'];

$buffer = new loginHandler ($log,$pwd,$em);
$buffer->send();
```

So when it's run, table fields are filled with "NULL" instead of the actual data from the inputs

Comment: Should be $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $ sign before _POST

```
$log = $_POST['log'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$em = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I made such a stupid mistake and couldn't figure it out in two hours.
But there goes another one, now it tries to fill the table with NULL.